# Reset redo/undo index [Tabulator]

Tags: indexing, reset, tabulator

I am using tabulator with the options redo/undo active. After saving the table to sql, I like to reset the redo/undo index to -1, so that the user cant use this options, because the data has already been saved.

Thanks in advance,

DJ

Comment: Adding some sample table data and (pseudo) code so show what you have tried already might attract people that can help you. Screenshots may help too.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in functionality for this (though that is a great idea, i will add it to the roadmap for the next release.

In the mean time refreshing the table data should do it:

```js
table.setData(table.getData());
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your sollution, and yes it works. Many thanks.

Adding it as a standard functionallity would be great.

Another thank for this.

DJ

Comment: If you found that my answer helped, please mark it as the answer to help others. also if you want to respond to an answer, please do in the the comments for that answer, dont post another answer as it make it hard for other users to find the answer they need. Cheers Oli :)